# How do I associate the post to a comic in custom form

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, create-view

My model looks like this:

```
    class ComicSeries(models.Model):
        """Model definition for ComicSeries."""

        # TODO: Define fields here
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Uploaded by: '
            )
        title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Series Title', max_length=500)
        cover = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Series cover', upload_to='comic_series', 
                height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None
            )
        description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Description')
        artist = models.CharField(verbose_name='Artist(s)', max_length=500)
        date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(default='')

class ComicIssue(models.Model):
    """Model definition for ComicIssue."""

    # TODO: Define fields here
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
            null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Uploaded by: '
        )
    title = models.ForeignKey(ComicSeries, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Series Title')
    issue = models.CharField(verbose_name='Issue Number', max_length=500)
    issue_title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Issue Title', max_length=1000)
    issue_cover = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Issue cover', upload_to='comic_issues', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None)
    issue_description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Description')
    issue_file = models.FileField(verbose_name='Issue file', upload_to='comic_issues_files', max_length=100,
        help_text='File in pdf or as single image'
    )
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    issue_slug = models.SlugField(default='')
```

views.py :

```
class ComicIssueCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = ComicIssue
    fields = ['issue_title', 'issue_cover', 'issue_description', 'issue_cover', 'issue_file']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(ComicIssueCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

I am able to select to which ComicSeries a ComicIssue belongs to in Django admin.

[In django admin there is an option to upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reS1D.png)

[But on my form, there is no field when I add 'title'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXeSw.png)

Template:

```
{% block body %}
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Add new comic issue/chapter</h2>
    <form class="form", action="", method="POST", enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group form">
            <span class="text-danger small">
                {{field.errors}}
            </span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
            {{field.label_tag}}
            {{field.help_text}}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">{{field}}</div>
      {% endfor %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn grey-text black">Add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

But I have a problem doing this in a custom form. Is there a way I can determine to which series an issue belongs to in a custom form using CreateView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed '**title**' in the fields specified in the view. Since **title** is the foreign key of ComicIssue to ComicSeries, You need to include that in the fields to achieve whats required

```
    class ComicIssueCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
        model = ComicIssue
        fields = ['title', 'issue_title', 'issue_cover', 'issue_description', 
                  'issue_cover', 'issue_file']

        def form_valid(self, form):
           form.instance.user = self.request.user
           return super(ComicIssueCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Updates:
The problem was due to not initializing the 'select' in MaterializeCSS. It is necessary to select field to work in MaterializeCSS

```
   <script> 
   $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('select').material_select(); 
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: When I add the title, it shows nothing on the form. The label is there but there are no options or a field to fill in.

Comment: Can you give the template at which the form is rendered?

Comment: I have added the template in the question

Comment: Yes. I'm using it.

Comment: If you are using MaterializeCSS then you need to initialize 'select' in order to make the select field work. Try adding this to your template     `<script>                                                         
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
  });                                                                                                 
 </script>` and update if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The fields in ComicIssueCreate should include title

So fields = ['title','issue_title', 'issue_cover', 'issue_description', 'issue_cover', 'issue_file']

Comment: When I add the title, it shows nothing on the form. The label is there but there are no options or a field to fill in.

Comment: You should add a couple of comic titles in admin first then with the comic title you can add specific comic issues which belong to a comic title or comic.

Comment: I have added links to the screenshots of how my form looks like when I add 'title'.